# How can I wrap the description in paragraph tags?

Tags: magento-1.9, php

On my product page I am getting the description like this:

```
<?php echo $attribute_value = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('my_description') ->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); ?>
```

The description is a multi-line attribute. How can I wrap each line of it in < p > tags?

Example:

```
Description Attribute:
Apple
Orange
Pear

Output:
<p>Apple</p>
<p>Orange</p>
<p>Pear</p>
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about PHP and not about Magento.

Comment: @mbalparda It is php specific to magento...

Comment: Can you give any example what u exact want?

Comment: @MagikVishal Added example of what I want

Comment: You can follow this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15013680/break-string-with-line-breaks-into-html-paragraphs-with-php/15013950#15013950 nothing Magento specific there, `$attributeValue` goes in, HTML goes out. I don't think this is built into Magento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by just using `str_replace`

```
<?php 
$attribute_value = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('my_description') ->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); 
echo "<p>".str_replace(PHP_EOL, "</p><p>", $attribute_value)."</p>";
?>
```

Also you can use an array functions :

```
<?php 
$attribute_value = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('my_description') ->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); 
$attr_array = explode(PHP_EOL, $attribute_value);
echo "<p>".implode('</p><p>', $attr_array)."</p>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code, hope it works,

```
$desc = "Apple
Orange
Pear";
$descarray = explode('\r\n', $desc);
foreach($descarray as $row){
    echo '<p>'.$row.'</p>';
}
```